# 'str' object has no attribute 'flatMap'

Tags: python, pyspark

I am quite new to Python. I have Anaconda3 – 4.4.0 installed with a PySpark kernel (Spark 2.2.0).

I am trying to test a simple script using a simple text file on my Windows 7 OS to make sure some of the capabilities of my Python installation works.

Here is my script:

```
 word_counts = ('C:\\Users\\oakins1p\\WeeklyMeeting.txt') \
.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()) \
.map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)\
.saveAsTextFile('C:\\Users\\oakins1p\\WeeklyMeetingOutput.txt')\`
```

I keep getting a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'flatMap'` and I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: You have a string and you're calling a method on it. Why do you think that a string would have that method?

Answer (score 4):

`word_counts` is a string, where one doesn't simply call `flatMap()` on it.

Try this reading the file with textFile() first, like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
word_counts = sc.textFile(filepath).flatMap()...
```

inspired by this [example](https://www.quora.com/Could-you-explain-the-word-count-example-line-by-line-in-Spark-I-see-some-examples-here-Examples-Apache-Spark).

Comment: Thanks for your help. That didn't work. But I ended up replacing

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App") 

with 

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

And it worked!

Comment: OK great @Rapcetera, I updated my answer. Now you can *accept* it, please (with the tick mark on the left of my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to read the file. Try using `textFile()` function of the SparkContext.

Comment: Its Python, not Scala